# Folders inside the webapps folder (css, jsp etc.) not getting copied in svn repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive, repository

I have recently created a svn repository and done a commit of my newly created maven web project. The problem is folders except WEB-INFand META-INF inside the src/main/webapps folder did not get copied in the repository (eg. css, javascript, jsp, images)......when I right click on one of these folders (from eclipse IDE)which haven't got copied and try to commit, the folders and its content doesn't get listed in the list of items to be copied and when I click finish get an error message 'At least 1 resource should be selected'. I even tried using subclipse instaed of subversive which I usually use. so my question is how to add these
folders into repository ??

Comment: Isn't it possible that these files and folders are marked as svn:ignore?

Comment: I found the answer myself friends - I had initially copied these folders from a project imported into my workspace from a different repository so the above mentioned folders contained .svn folder pointing to that repository and hence the problem :)

Comment: Post an answer with your fix and then mark it as accepted. That way people can see that this question is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had initially copied these folders from a project imported into my workspace from a different repository so the above mentioned folders contained .svn folder pointing to that repository and hence the problem :)